# Arrangements in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $10$ people sitting in a circle. $4$ men and $6$ women.How many arrangements will be there if men do not appear consecutively?

Comment: Provide more information, please. Are the men and women distinguishable? I.e. does swapping around two women result in a different arrangement?

Comment: They are all unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting the $6$ women sit down will be $\frac{6!}{6} = 120$ different ways.

Then just insert the $4$ men into the $6$ gaps, so that no two men are in the same gap. This results in a factor of $6 \times 5 \times 4\times 3 = 360$.

So the total is $120 \times 360 = 43200$.

Comment: Rotations aren't taking into account in your answer, @WhatsUp

Comment: In the step of counting women, I divided by $6$ hence taking the rotations into account.

Comment: That makes sense. It's odd that we differ by a factor $10$, though...

Comment: Lol don't understand the downvote...

Comment: It's mine. I'm sadly unable to remove it (I've tried) until you edit the post. I suggest putting the fraction on the first line as $\frac{6!}{6}$?

Comment: Ah... OK, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Men: Andrew, Bart, Charles and Damocles, Destroyer of Worlds

Women: Alice, Barbara, Cynthia, Diana, Elsa and Francine.

Put Andrew somewhere in the circle. There's seven slots left for the remaining three men (as you can't put them in Andrew's spot or next to him). There are ten different ways to arrange the three remaining men:

M X M X M X X

M X M X X M X

M X M X X X M

M X X M X M X

M X X M X X M

X M X M X M X

X M X M X X M

X M X X M X M

X X M X M X M

(look up 'stars-and-bars combinatorics' if you want to research the more general method to solve this)

We now have $3! = 6$ ways of seating the men, and $6! = 720$ men of seating the women, leading to a result of $4320 \cdot 10 = 43200$.

(Fixing Andrew's seat got rid of the permutations possible by rotating the circle)

Comment: I think you missed arrangements like "M X X M X M X" etc.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, and I also failed to multiply by the number of arrangements. We seem to be in accord now.

Comment: +1 for Stars and Bars

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

"Glue" a man to the right of each woman consider these pairs as one unit. This way you ensured that when you arrange these units and the two remaining woman there wont be consecutive men. Use circular permutation.

Hope this helped

Comment: Yup, just don't forget to count the number of ways to glue them together, if that matters.